# Type mismatch in VBA FormulaR1C1 that removes values past "-" sign

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a simple macro that moves down to the last filled cell, then moves to the right and is supposed to put the following formula in there: "=LEFT(RC[-2], SEARCH(" - ",RC[-2])-1)", that takes the value from two cells to the left and removes all characters after the "-".

```
Range("B1").End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select

Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-2], SEARCH(" - ",RC[-2])-1)"
```

The problem is that when I run the code I get Type Mismatch error. The cell that the code goes into is blank before the code runs.

Comment: Double the quotes in the string: `"=LEFT(RC[-2], SEARCH("" - "",RC[-2])-1)"`

Comment: Thanks! That solves the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA uses double quotes (") to demark string literals.  For example:

```
const saying = "you look nice today"
```

The problem arises when you want to have a double quote inside a string literal as follows:

```
const saying = "you look "nice" today"
```

In this case, the VBA interpreter understants the value of the saying constant to be "you look " as if you had written:

```
const saying = "you look "
```

But then it gets to the word 'nice' and it is confused because it is not syntactically valid.  There are a couple of ways to get a double quote into a string literal in VBA.  The first way is to use string concatenation and the chr() function.  The chr() function returns a character based on it numeric value from the ASCII table.  Every character has a numeric value that underlies it.  "A" is number 65, "B" is number 66 and so on,  The ASCII number the double quote character is 34.  So a statement of:

```
debug.print chr(65) & chr(66) & chr(34)
```

would display the following

```
AB"
```

So you could wirte:

```
debug.print "you look " & chr(34) & "nice" & chr(34) & " today"
```

and it would display:

```
you look "nice" today
```

But I think you will agree with me that this approach seems very onerous, so there is a shortcut when trying to put a double quote into a string literal.  It seems a bit strange, but you need to put two double quotes instead of one. So the following code:

```
debug.print "you look ""nice"" today"
```

will print:

```
you look "nice" today
```

I hope this explanation helps.